# Bash's errexit inside of a function behaves unexpectedly depending on calling context

Tags: bash

I have `errexit` set inside of a Hudson job so that it will die as soon as some component command fails. This has generally been working great until I added some error checking, and now it's not behaving as I would expect it to.

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Some sample code:

**/tmp/foo**

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
errexit_test()
{
    set -o errexit

    BIN=$1; shift

    /tmp/bar $BIN
    /tmp/baz
}
```

**/tmp/bar**

```
$ cat /tmp/bar
#!/bin/bash

BIN=$1

/bin/$BIN
EXIT_CODE=$?

echo "done bar"
exit $EXIT_CODE
```

**/tmp/baz**

```
$ cat /tmp/baz
#!/bin/bash

echo "done baz"
```

Running them inside of a shell started with `-e` gives the expected results:

**no error**

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash -e
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ . /tmp/foo
$ errexit_test true
done bar
done baz
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```

**with error**

```
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ errexit_test false
done bar
$ echo $SHLVL
1
```

If try to intercept the error, I succeed -- sort of. The inner function no longer stops executing as I think it should:

```
$ errexit_test false || /bin/true
done bar
done baz
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```

What I would like is for the *function* to still halt execution immediately, but the calling program should continue or not depending on the exit code from the right side of the `||`.

There seems to be something else going on that I don't understand. Add in another script:

**/tmp/extra**

```
$ cat /tmp/extra
#!/bin/bash

echo "in extra"
```

and that behaves as expected when combined with a command/program:

```
$ /tmp/extra
in extra
$ /bin/true || /tmp/extra
$ /bin/false || /tmp/extra
in extra
```

but not when combined with the function:

```
$ errexit_test false || /tmp/extra
done bar
done baz
```

These two issues may be unrelated, but I feel that they are, though I can't figure out how or why.

Comment: Both of these answer my question -- why couldn't I have found them earlier? Thank you both.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside-subshells-with-parenthesis-followed-by-an-or